# How to customize Bootstrap JS Popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I designed `HTML` page with age selector using `Bootstrap JS Popover` I get following output 1 and i want to achieve output 2 and following tasks

1. `li` list as liner as the output 2.
2. `li` should clickable and once click `li` it should appear in button text.

**output 1**

[image]

**output 2**

[image]

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#age-select-1').popover({
     content: "<ul><li>18</li><li>19</li><li>20</li><li>21</li><li>22</li><li>23</li><li>24</li><li>25</li></ul>",
     html: true,
     trigger: "focus",
     placement: "bottom"
   });
 });
```

```css
#age-select-1 li {
  float: left;    /*not working*/
  display: inline; /*not working*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <label class="label nav-label">Age</label>
    <button class="btn nav-age-select" id="age-select-1">21</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: check your `ul,li`'s margins and paddings, and seems your css selector doesn't match target `ul`, better add classes directly to `ul` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed CSS on the list - gave it it's own class

Basically the browser adds it's own padding so we simply reshape it, set the width to 25% and you have your effect

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#age-select-1').popover({
     content: "<ul class='foo'><li>18</li><li>19</li><li>20</li><li>21</li><li>22</li><li>23</li><li>24</li><li>25</li></ul>",
     html: true,
     trigger: "click",
     placement: "bottom"
   });
 });
```

```css
.foo { padding-left: 0; }
.foo li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <label class="label nav-label">Age</label>
    <button class="btn nav-age-select" id="age-select-1">21</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do u have idea of making `li` as clickable.  i used this  `$(".foo li").click(function () {   
                           alert("test");          
                        });`

Comment: Change it to: `$(document).on("click", ".foo li", function () { alert("test"); });` -it's being added after the dom has been initially set up so you have find it within the document again

Answer (score 1):

this `#age-select-1 li` will not work because the `li` are not insde the `#age-select-1` elements but you can give the `ul` an id and change your css to `#column li`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#age-select-1').popover({
     content: "<ul id='column'><li>18</li><li>19</li><li>20</li><li>21</li><li>22</li><li>23</li><li>24</li><li>25</li></ul>",
     html: true,
     trigger: "focus",
     placement: "bottom"
   });
 });
```

```css
#column li {
  float: left;    /* working*/
  display: inline; /* working*/
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <label class="label nav-label">Age</label>
    <button class="btn nav-age-select" id="age-select-1">21</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```